# Fix the seed for the community module in Python that uses networkx module

Tags: python, networkx

I am using the community module to extract communities from a networkx graph. For the community module, the order in which the nodes are processed makes a difference. I tried to set the seed of random to get consistent results but that is not working. Any idea on how to do this?

thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about what code you are using and what you have tried?  SO works best if you provide a small code example showing your problem.

Comment: Thanks Aric, The only issue is that my code constructs a nx.Graph() from objects of a class I created by iterating over an array of objects and adding them to the graph one at a time. So what I will do is close this question, prepare some code, and re-post it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the seed inside every class I used.